# Subclassing a UILabel, Given a Warning

Tags: overriding, uilabel, subclass

I have the following at the top of one of my UIViewControllers.m:

```
@implementation UILabel (Custom)
-(void)setTitleLabelColor
{
UIColor *titleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.90196 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

self.textColor = titleColor;

}

@end
```

I basically want to have a method that makes the text color to yellow.

When I call that function, it always gives me a warning, saying the UILabel might not respond to it, but it works fine.

How can I get rid of the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also declare this in your header (`.h`) file. For example,

```
@interface UILabel (Custom)
-(void)setTitleLabelColor;
@end
```

Then `#import` this from another file when you want to use that method.